# Difference between direct and sequential file access in C

Tags: c, file, structure, sequential

I am not quite sure if I understand difference between direct and sequential file accessing in C. Lets say we have a structure in some file:

```
struct students_s {
    int points[5];
    int number[10];
    int id;
}student;
```

In this case we can use direct access to that structure since all of the variables are the same type, therefore they are same fixed size. This is my thinking, and I am not quite sure if it is correct. Can someone please help me with this?

Another question I have is, is it necessary that students in that file are arranged from 1 to n with the `id` variable or their arrangemenet does not matter?

I tried searching for it online but I can not seem to find detailed answer.

Comment: what is it you want help with? it is not clear what the question is.

Comment: AFAIK, "direct" and "sequential" are relatively old-fashioned terms from the Pleistocene era of mainframes and "Big Iron".  They don't really apply today.  C's I/O model is that you can read/write as many bytes as you want, sequentially.  But you can also use `fseek` to jump to wherever you want, and one way that's useful is if you know you've written a bunch of fixed-size records — like with your `student` struct.

Comment: You can read more at Wikipedia about [Record-oriented filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record-oriented_filesystem)s, although that page doesn't define the terms "direct" and "sequential", either.

Comment: I know them as [random access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) files meaning that with fixed size records you can seek directly to any record and read or write it.